# Best practices for streaming response of WCF webservice

Tags: wcf, web-services, streaming, stream

I'm trying to pull a large amount of data out of a WCF web service.  The request is fairly small and the response message will be very big.  Currently the web service is throwing SystemOutOfMemory exceptions due a limitation on IIS6 for the memory it can allocated (~1.4GB).

I have read in some blogs that implementing streaming will solve my problem.

Can anybody share their experiences with this topic? I'm most interested in any sample client-side & service-side code that can be shared or any recommendations/best practices.  MemoryStream vs FileStream? Return type should be Stream, Message, Byte[]?

My operation looks like the following: (typically it will return a big number of elements in the response array, ~200K elements)

```
MediumSizeResponseClass[] GetData(SmallSizeRequestClass request)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to stream back only the response, then use `transferMode=streamedResponse` in your binding configuration. This makes sure only the returned response will be streamed.

The return value of a streaming function must be a `Stream`. You can then read from that stream and do whatever you need to do with it (store it, analyse it, whatever).

So basically you'd have a service contract something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IYourService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream GetData(SmallSizeRequestClass request);
}
```

On the server, you basically just write to a stream, while on the client, you read from the stream.

Have you consulted the MSDN docs on [WCF Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx)?

Comment: Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx for examples which can be found at the bottom of the page that marc linked to above.

Comment: Thansk Mark,  I'm somehow familiar with the basics of implementing streaming.  I know there is different ways of implenting it, some developers will use a Message as return type as opposed to a Stream class.  Some will use a FileStream while others a MemoryStream. 

I'm trying to collect feedback, cons an pros on the different implementations for Streaming in WCF.

Comment: @Damian: ok, excellent. Well, I haven't had much first-hand experience with streaming in WCF myself, but I would say: use whatever stream makes sense. It's gotta be a stream, a stream, a stream - but which type is largely irrelevant. If you already have files on the server - use FileStream. If you need to load a blob from a database table - use a MemoryStream. I'm not aware of any major issues with using one type of stream vs. another. But maybe someone else can enlighten us some more!

Comment: Isn't the problem with the MemoryStream approach going to be that you'd end up loading all the contents before returning the stream?  If you're returning large files you'd end up with a bottleneck wouldn't you?

Comment: @spooner Yes, [How to return stream from WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582409/how-to-return-stream-from-wcf-service) question has relevant answers.