# How to handle when calling Web Service Async-methods which takes long time to return result

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

Say I have a webservice which has Async methods.

How to handle below situations when calling this web service

1. what code I need to add to below code to handle this situation that the web service may take a while to return records?
2. in try-catch statement in below code, what http status should I look out for? Example : Fail, success, complete if there is error ?
3. If there is connection issue over network AFTER a while reading records, how to get the last record returned?
4. How to show the Progress status to show record retrieving is still not finished? use this for above Q(1)?

Thanks.

```
private async void CallTaskTButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

     Task _asyncCustomer = Class1.Customer.Listing.GetAsyncRecords()


      foreach (wsCustomerList.Customer_List _List in _asyncCustomer.Result)
      {

        //-- code --

      }


    }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {

   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the service call may take a while, make sure to update the timeout settings for the service call. Once the service you're calling gets a timeout error, that's all you'll get returned: a timeout error. Here's something that might help you out: [Stream a response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403030/571881)